# How to load a json file in .NET MAUI?

Tags: json, maui

I created a json file in the Resources/Raw and I made the build generation action to MauiAsset. I used the following code to load the json file but I got a not found file exception.

````
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var json = LoadMauiAsset();
    }

    async Task LoadMauiAsset()
    {
        try
        {
            using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("drugs.json");
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            var contents = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 5):

The code that you pasted won't even compile, or at the very least will never give you the result you're after. I have modified your code a bit and verified that this works.

```cs
    private async void OnButtonClickedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var json = await LoadMauiAsset();
        await DisplayAlert("", json, "OK");
    }

    async Task<string> LoadMauiAsset()
    {
        try
        {
            using var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("foo.json");
            using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "";
        }

    }
```

As you already mentioned, you will need to add the `drugs.json` in the `Resources\Raw\` file and mark it with the `MauiAsset` build action. To double-check, open your csproj file and make sure that this line is there: `<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />` this makes sure that everything under the afore mentioned folder is included as an asset.

and no other mention of your `drugs.json` file. There might be an entry like this:

```xml
    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="Resources\Raw\foo.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

Which is fine, but you can remove it as well.

Comment: Thanks for this answer but this does not work if we add a file in Raw folder as "Link". My file is in different assembly and I want to read in core project via this method but throws file not found exception if adding as a link. Thoughts?

Comment: Hmm I would expect it to work, as a link it just gets copied there I think. If you can provide a little repo project with what you're doing I can have a look